# Why echo fails on element of an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, echo

I wrote this script that apparently has no problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0
LOGS=/home/badouble/bABaReC/CDAS_Selection_log

for dir in $DATA/*/
do
     dir=${dir%*/}
     echo $dir
     ARR=$(echo $dir | tr "/" " ")
     echo ${ARR[1]}   

 done
```

But it does not produce the desired output, here below:

```
/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2011-12

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-01

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-02

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-03

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-04

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-05

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-06

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-07

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-08

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-09

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-10

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-11

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2012-12

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2013-01

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2013-02

/home/badouble/STORE/rawData_v1r0/2013-03
```

Instead of the blank line it should print the second element of array $ARR.

Why doesn't it?

Comment: Please show a desired output to make it easier for us!

Comment: come on, is trivial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *capture* the output of echo into `( )`:

```
ARR=( $(echo $dir | tr "/" " ") )
```

or

```
 ARR=( `echo $dir | tr "/" " "` )
```

Or dispense with the `tr` altogether:

```
ARR=( `echo ${dir//\// }` )
```

by using substitution in the expansion: `${var//from/to}` with `\/` escaped as the "from".
Or better still (more robust), dispense with the sub-process altogether:

```
ARR=( ${dir//\/ /} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `echo` or `tr` to do this.

To create an array, simply use `IFS` and `read` as shown below, which is more efficient because these are shell built-in commands:

```
IFS=/ read -a ARR <<< "$dir"
echo "${ARR[1]}"
```

Comment: This looks very professional, I will use it in my next script ;-) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One extra brackets:

```
ARR=($(echo $dir | tr "/" " "))
```

`x=$(command)`  This will assign the result of the command to the variable x

`x=($(command))` This will first execute the command and the result is stored in array x